# To get the newline in textfile

Tags: android, textview, text-files, assets

I have my textfile stored in assets folder and my requirement is to show the contents in textview pointwise.I am able to access the contents if there is no space in text file which is stored in assets folder.If I puts the space in the text file then i am not able to get the contents after space.How to achieve this means to show the contents pointwise.
for example my textfile is as follows

a)Americab)Africac)India

I want output as

a) America

b) Africa

c) India

```
Here is my code to access the text file from assest folder which I am getting.

InputStream in = this.getAssets().open("detailtext.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            line = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: Why can't you store it that way in the file itself?

Comment: If store the contents like that manner I am getting just result as a) America i.e chracters before space.I dont know what is the reason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you need to read multiple lines, you need to loop through, till you reach the EOF. Try something like this:-

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(0);
InputStream in = this.getAssets().open("detailtext.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append("\n");
}
String wholeText = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only reading one line, you need to use a while loop and continue to read each line until the end of the file

```
InputStream in = this.getAssets().open("detailtext.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    // do whatever with line
}
```